# Rudimentary ways to measure execution time of a method

Tags: objective-c

What object/method would I call to get current time in milliseconds (or great precision) to help measure how long a method took to execute?

NSDate's timeIntervalSinceDate will return NSInterval which is measured in seconds. I am looking for something finer grained, something similar to Java's System.currentTimeMillis.

Is there an equivalent version in objective-c/CocoaTouch?

Comment: The reason I am using some quick and dirty in-my-code timing is because I wanted to narrow down an area that seemed problematic and I wasn't having any luck getting very much information after I ran Instruments and Shark. So to avoid being stuck, I was opting for this route.

Comment: dispatch_benchmark() is one way: http://nshipster.com/benchmarking/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, `+[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]` returns an `NSTimeInterval`, which is a typedef for a double.  The docs say

> NSTimeInterval is always specified in seconds; it yields sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years.

So it's safe to use for millisecond-precision timing.  I do so all the time.

Comment: You loose a lot of time just calling `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`, this biases the result in an unpredictable way.

Comment: Downvoted because - experimentally - as @GeorgSchölly says, Apple has implemented NSDate to be *extremely slow* (at least on iOS). It is mosly useless - their "timeInterval*" method calls actually showed up in Instruments as the biggest CPU hog on one project!

Comment: My experience on iOS with NSDate based (MGBenchmark specifically) solutions is that while testing every single line in the loop individually, I found almost no discernable difference between them. Mach_time revealed not only more accurate results but it also had the performance-eating lines of code truly stand out.

Answer (score 25):

For very fine-grained timings on OS X, I use `mach_absolute_time( )`, which is defined in `<mach/mach_time.h>`.  You can use it as follows:

```
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static double ticksToNanoseconds = 0.0;

uint64_t startTime = mach_absolute_time( );
// Do some stuff you want to time here
uint64_t endTime = mach_absolute_time( );

 // Elapsed time in mach time units
uint64_t elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;

// The first time we get here, ask the system
// how to convert mach time units to nanoseconds
if (0.0 == ticksToNanoseconds) {
    mach_timebase_info_data_t timebase;
    // to be completely pedantic, check the return code of this next call.
    mach_timebase_info(&timebase);
    ticksToNanoseconds = (double)timebase.numer / timebase.denom;
}

double elapsedTimeInNanoseconds = elapsedTime * ticksToNanoseconds;
```

Comment: `double elapsedTimeInNanoseconds = elapsedTime / ticksToNanoseconds;`

Answer (score 4):

*Do not use `NSDate` for this.* You're loosing a lot of precision to call methods and instantiate objects, maybe even releasing something internal. You just don't have enough control.

Use either `time.h` or as [Stephen Canon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615998/rudimentary-ways-to-measure-execution-time-of-a-method/1616376#1616376) suggested `mach/mach_time.h`. They are both much more accurate.

The best way to do this is to fire up Instruments or Shark, attach them to your process (works even if it's already running) and let them measure the time a method takes.

After you're familiar with it this takes even less time than any put-in-mach-time-functions-and-recompile-the-whole-application solution. You even get a lot of information extra. I wouldn't settle for anything less.

Comment: NB: there are use-cases where Instruments is useless. e.g.  an OpenGL app - I need to know which shaders are running fast vs. slow, and which background methods are taking up how much time ... on end-user's devices. In some cases, I want to switch to different rendering path dynamically as a result. Can't ask them to run Instruments ;), and that would prevent runtime changes anyway, so ... time/mach_time is good.

Answer (score 2):

`timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` is perfectly fine.

However, unless it's a long-running method, this won't bear much fruit.  Execution times can vary wildly when you're talking about a few millisecond executions.  If your thread/process gets preempted mid-way through, you'll have non-deterministic spikes.  Essentially, your sample size is too small.  Either use a profiler or run 100,000 iterations to get total time and divide by 100,000 to get average run-time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to tune your code's performance, you would do better to use Instruments or Shark to get an overall picture of where your app is spending its time.

Answer (score 1):

I will repost my answer from another post here. Note that my admittedly simple solution to this complex problem uses NSDate and NSTimeInterval as its foundation:

---

I know this is an old one but even I found myself wandering past it again, so I thought I'd submit my own option here.

Best bet is to check out my blog post on this:
[Timing things in Objective-C: A stopwatch](http://metal-sole.com/2012/01/24/timing-things-in-objective-c-a-stopwatch/)

Basically, I wrote a class that does stop watching in a very basic way but is encapsulated so that you only need to do the following:

```
[MMStopwatchARC start:@"My Timer"];
// your work here ...
[MMStopwatchARC stop:@"My Timer"];
```

And you end up with:

```
MyApp[4090:15203]  -> Stopwatch: [My Timer] runtime: [0.029]
```

in the log...

Again, check out my post for a little more or download it here:
[MMStopwatch.zip](http://metal-sole.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/MMStopwatch.zip)

Comment: As noted above: you shouldn't use NSDate. Also, this answer really adds nothing, it simple repackages the existing (broken) approach in extra indirection, which doesn't help

Comment: I beg to differ here. NSDate is fine for certain operations. As I stated it is a simplistic solution to a very difficult question. I'd agree that the exactness of the chosen answer is certainly a better choice. That said, I still like using 2 quick lines of code to get an idea of the times in my programs.

Answer (score 0):

@bladnman  I love your stopwatch thing.. I use it all the time..  Here's a little block I wrote that eliminates the need for the closing call, and makes it even EASIER (if that even seemed possible) to use, lol.

```
+(void)stopwatch:(NSString*)name timing:(void(^)())block {
    [MMStopwatch start:name];
    block();
    [MMStopwatch stop: name];
}
```

then you can just call it wherever..

```
[MMStopwatch stopwatch:@"slowAssFunction" timing:^{
    NSLog(@"%@",@"someLongAssFunction");
}];
```

↪`someLongAssFunction`

```
-> Stopwatch: [slowAssFunction] runtime:[0.054435]
```

You should post that sucker to github - so people can find it easily / contribute, etc.  it's great.  thanks.

Comment: Great! I like it. Using it in a block makes sense. Very cool.